# Stripe Webhook - calling slow cloud email service from it

Tags: email, stripe-payments, webhooks

We have the following 2 questions:

1. We want to send email to our subscriber from our Stripe-registered payment webhook.
   Email service is on the cloud and can be quick or pretty slow.
   As we already know, a webhook is a time-sensitive thing and easily times out.
   What can we do to address that?
2. Will sending emails in async, rather than sync way from the webhook suffice?

We tried to call email service in async way - it works but takes a couple of seconds to complete. Is this long enough to cause a timeout in web hook?

Answer (score 0):

From Stripe's docs:

> Your endpoint must quickly return a successful status code (2xx) prior to any complex logic that could cause a timeout. For example, you must return a 200 response before updating a customer’s invoice as paid in your accounting system.

So the idea is that your 200 message as soon as you get the webhook to signal "my server received the event" and *then* you start doing the heavy work like sending emails.

It also sounds like sending the email async would be well within Stripe's webhook timeout window so that may be a viable solution in your case.

Comment: "must quickly return a successful status code (2xx)" was a most confusing part. So, do you say that we should   return              
                               context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
and then do the section below:
                // 1. lookup the payment in the database and update order status                         
                // 2. call seller's webhook notifying that payment was success                // 3. send confirmation email to seller  
and then do
                return;
? Is setting context.Response.StatusCode to 200 enough?

Comment: Yes, that is the suggestion from the docs: return 200, then do the processing on your side. Returning 200 is how you tell Stripe that you successfully received the event, so yes if {context.Response.StatusCode = 200} is how you send that 200 back then that is a good way to tell Stripe that you received the event.